# golang net.LookupTXT returns 'no such host'

Tags: go, dns

With go I get the message "no such host" when I try to get the TXT record of some hosts.

I would have expected something like "No TXT record".

Is the "no such host" message considered to be treated as "no TXT record"?

Here is my small test program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    txt, err := net.LookupHost("mail10476.emails3.rightmove.co.uk")
    fmt.Printf("Host Lookup\n %v\n %v\n", txt, err)
    txt, err = net.LookupTXT("mail10476.emails3.rightmove.co.uk")
    fmt.Printf("TXT  Lookup\n %v\n %v\n", txt, err)
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me (tried with 1.17 and 1.21); `host -t txt` returns "no TXT records". Please consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=is%3Aissue+in%3Atext+LookupTXT).

Comment: Done @kostix https://github.com/golang/go/issues/65288

Comment: BTW, while the discussion in #65288 is going on, I could recommend looking at [`github.com/miekg/dns`](https://github.com/miekg/dns) for a possible stop-gap solution to your problem (which, ostensibly, is to have sensible results of resolving of TXT records).